# Leaving a blank cell in Excel until data entered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I’m struggling with an IF formula and hoping someone will know the answer.

I’m trying to keep cell S2 blank (which has the formula =O2/H2) until a value is entered into cell R3.

Does anyone know if this is possible to do.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is this in Excel of some other spreadsheet software?

Comment: @Mokubai the title says Excel.

Comment: @LPChip I should probably start reading titles, apparently people put some useful information there sometimes ;)

Comment: That's not the worst, I've seen people put very crucial info only in the tags and blaming me for not understanding what it is about. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel I typically use a variant of the following:

```
=IF(R3<>"",O2/H2,"")
```

Which essentially means `if there is anything in R3 then calculate O2/H2, otherwise show nothing`

The basic format of the `IF` command in Excel is

```
IF(condition, then do this, otherwise do this)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Been trying to work out a formula for that for an hour now!

Comment: @JackRichardson if Mokubai helped you, and you no longer need help, feel free to press the checkmark next to the answer to indicate that you no longer need help. If not, please let us know what you need help with. Also... +1 from me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be simply to leave the `=O2/H2` formula in `S2` untouched
and use conditional formatting to make it appear blank if `R3` is empty. 
Use “Use a formula to determine which cells to format”,
enter `=R3=""` as the formula,
and set the format to a custom number format of `;;;`
(or set the font color to white). 
This way, other cells’ formulas can refer to `S2` and get its real value;
it just won’t be displayed. 
(I don’t know whether you would consider that to be a benefit or a drawback.)